# Convert a Json string to C# class object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I have a json string like `{field:'DateToEnd',dir:'asc'}`

And i have a class in c# with following two properties.

```
public class SortDescriptor
{
    public SortDescriptor()
    {
    }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Dir { get; set; }
}
```

Now i want to convert this string to the class object so that i can access the properties.

I tried the following example. But it's not working for me.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
SortDescriptor sort = (SortDescriptor)serialize.DeserializeObject(fixSortString);
```

It gives following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]' to type 'NF.Common.SortDescriptor'.
```

Can anyone let me know that how i can do this?

Comment: Use json.net from nuget (newtonsoft.json)

Comment: `serialize.Deserialize<SortDescriptor>(fixSortString);`

Comment: @JeremyThompson I have edited my question.

Comment: @GeneR It works for me. Thanks.

Comment: That's my 2nd answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure **DeserializeObject** requires a type as a second parameter, eg

```
JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer();
SortDescriptor sort = (SortDescriptor)serialize.DeserializeObject(fixSortString, typeof(SortDescriptor));
```

Or using Generics:

```
JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer(); 
SortDescriptor sort = (SortDescriptor)serialize.DeserializeObject<SortDescriptor>(fixSortString);
```